# How can I start showing a paging-enabled UIScrollView in the middle view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I have a simple problem but I can't figure it out. I have a UIScrollView with three nested UIWebViews. I need to be able to "recycle" these views to actually scroll through lots of content.

My main problem is that I can't figure out how to show a view that isn't the very first, meaning that you can immediately swipe back from. Right now I have three views paging, but it starts at the first one, and you can move right two.

What can I do to make it so that I am always in the middle? With the ability to always swipe right OR left?

Thanks!

Comment: "I have a UIScrollView with three nested UIWebViews." - you should not add scroll views on top of each other.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's incorrect. It's totally fine to put multiple UIScrollViews on top of each other. In this case, there'll be extra work to manage the scrolling and swiping gestures, *but* that doesn't mean it's something that "should not" be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods for your viewController, try adding the following bit of code:

```
[self.myMainScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,self.view.frame.size.width) animated:NO];
```

That'll scroll your larger scrollview over, so that the middle `UIWebView` is visible.

If that doesn't help, dig around in the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) documentation - you should find some good stuff there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't contentOffset want a CGPoint? Not a CGSize?